# Facebook Like, Comment and Share links via API feed

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I've created a Facebook feed using the Graph API which simply displays a few of the latest posts from a Facebook Page.

I've also done the same with the Twitter API, and within those tweets displayed I have created Retweet, Reply and Favourite buttons using their Web Intents.

e.g.; `https://twitter.com/intent/like?tweet_id=<?php echo $tweets[0]['id']; ?>`

However, I'm struggling to find a way to do a similar thing with the Facebook feed. Simply a Comment, Like and Share button as above.

**I'm aware Facebook provides it's own embeddable plugins/buttons but those are not what I'm looking for.**

Facebook's own stuff is ugly and would not look great in the design. I'm looking for a URL or something that allows me to create my own buttons.

Is there a way to do so at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Only sharing is possible by linking to a specific URL (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web), commenting and liking is not. (Comments and likes can be published via API though - but that would require that users login to your app and grant it permission first.)

Comment: I thought as much. Cheers @CBroe